# Java. Prevent enlarging of Button

Tags: java, swing, awt

How to prevent Button from UpSize? I use a vertical Box with 2 lines, in first line → horizontal Box with many controls, in second line → Button, but button very enlarged, how to prevent this irritating behavior?

I was tried to set maximum size of button, it is works, but How to calculate this size correctly?

Sorry, I bad speak English.

Example:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class TEST{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame mainWindow = new Frame("hello");
        Box vertBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        mainWindow.add(vertBox);

        Box firstLine = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        vertBox.add(firstLine);
        SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(100, 0, 200, 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            firstLine.add(new JSpinner(sm));
            firstLine.add(new Label("Hello"));
        }

        Box secondLine = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        vertBox.add(secondLine);
        secondLine.add(new JProgressBar());
        secondLine.add(new Button("RUN-THIS"));

        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to show us some code ?

Sidenote: Hey, you use capital I, you speak better English than some (English) people around here on the web.

Comment: The layout manager (class extending LayoutManager) is the one responsible to set size and position of all components (the buttons in this case) that were added to a container. Each LayoutManager specialization has its own way of doing this. The GridLayout for example, will divide evenly the available space in the container among components, stretching or shrinking them accordingly. Other layout managers like FlowLayout wont change component sizes. But as @Charlie just said it's hard to make sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Seeing all your imports, isn't `import java.awt.*; import javax.swing.*;` much better ?

Comment: It is all NetBeans, I not yet configure it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Button, but button very enlarged, how to prevent this irritating behavior?

Don't use AWT components in a Swing application!

Swing components start with "J". You should be using JFrame, JLabel, JButton. This will fix your problem. A JButton will automatically calculate the maximum size equal to the preferred size and BoxLayout will respect this.

Also, class name should only start with a single upper case character. "TEST" should be "Test".

Comment: Thank you, when I replaced  AWT components by Swing, this problem was disappears.